# how to add searchbar using search view in the listFragment using OncreateOptionMenu

Tags: android

I want to add a search bar using `SearchView` inside my `ListFragment` for that I used `setOnQueryTextListner` inside `onCreateOptionMenu`. But I don't know how to make it work and I have a list created in string.xml file. How do I get that?

home_fragment.java

```
    public class home_fragment extends ListFragment  {

    ListView lst;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        lst = v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         return v;
    }
```

The following is for passing intent in the listview:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.songs, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Lyrics.class);
                    intent.putExtra("SongName", lst.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

The Followingis for the searchView :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);


        MenuItem searchitem =menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView) searchitem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                return false;
            }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: they all are in the same file...i.e....home_fragment.java.....